# how to read text, image, and video from .doc file in asp.net

Tags: c#, office-interop

i have a doc( ms word) file. and in this file have text, image and video, i want to read this text, image and video from this file. this file saved in my project folder.

i try a lot but i read only text. but i want to read text and images and video. but i don't know how can i do?. please help

i tried below code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();

string filePath = FileContent;
object file = filePath;
object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref file,
ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
ref nullobj);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc1 = wordApp.ActiveDocument;
string m_Content = doc1.Content.Text.ToString().Replace("\r","<br />");
```

thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

For images try this:
[Extract images from .doc file](http://forums.asp.net/t/1474743.aspx)